# What is wrong with this trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to set only one row actived.
If somebody try to set the estrutura_versao_status as 1, set every other estrutura_versao_status to 0 before and keep this new row as the only one estrutura_versao_status = 1.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_classifica_ativa_revisao BEFORE INSERT ON `sys_estrutura`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.estrutura_versao_status = 1) THEN
        UPDATE `sys_estrutura` SET estrutura_versao_status = 0;
    END IF;
END;
```

This is the error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to set the flag for the newly inserted row, just use assign that to the `NEW` variable. There is no need to do an UPDATE on the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_classifica_ativa_revisao BEFORE INSERT ON sys_estrutura
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.estrutura_versao_status = 1) THEN
        SET NEW.estrutura_versao_status = 0;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I GET THIS ERROR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: The point was that there is to be only one entry in the table which has estrutura_versao_status set to 1 (I guess).

Comment: You are not showing us everything then. The syntax works for me (using MySQL 5.5). How exactly do you run this? Which tool do you use to run this?

Comment: Sorry, it's MYSQL 5.36.1 , i'm trying on phpmyadmin.